# How to access a class attribute to layer a text box within a frame using Tkinter and Python3 - Layout not working right

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm having an issue where when I try to write my GUI application using classes, I can't get the layout right. Maybe it's because I'm new to OOP with Python, but I can't get the Tk.TextBox widget to properly scale and position itself within the GUI.

If I write my GUI without any classes and build the GUI straight, then I get the results I want perfectly. The problem is when I separate a Frame class that I'm using for a particular page, and then I create another class inheriting from Tk.Text and try to place the box underneath the Page Frame. I've tried accessing the Page class in the init method for the Text class, but I get an unresolved attribute error. Below is the code I'm using, I've edited out a bunch of button functions and loggers to keep it as minimal as possible.

```
class SNMPPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('SNMP Get Set Test')
        self.filename = None
        self.process = None
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.grid()
        '''' Input Boxes'''
        tk.Label(self, text='IP Address').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.EW)
        tk.Label(self, text="Edited").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.EW)
        tk.Label(self, text="#edited").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        tk.Label(self, text="Timeout (in seconds)").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.EW)

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.e3 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.e4 = tk.Entry(self)

        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.e1.insert(10, '#edited out')
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.e2.insert(10, '#edite out')
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.e3.insert(10, '#edited Out')
        self.e4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        self.e4.insert(10, '180')

        ''' Buttons'''
        tk.Button(self, text='Run SNMP Get/Set', command=self.start_batch_callback).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit_batch_program).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Button(self, text='Create Batch', command=self.create_batch).grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Button(self, text='Ping', command=self.start_ping_callback).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

class TextBox(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, state='disabled', wrap='word', bg='black', fg='green', font='fixedsys')
        self.init_textbox()

    def init_textbox(self):
        self.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        tk.Button(self, text='Clear', command=self.clear_button).grid(row=7, column=3, sticky=tk.W)

    def clear_button(self):
        try:
            self.config(state='normal')
            self.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        except Exception as e:
            loggermodule.module_logger.debug(e)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = SNMPPage(root)
    mytext = TextBox()
    stderrHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    loggermodule.module_logger.addHandler(stderrHandler)
    guiHandler = GuiHandlerText(mytext)
    guiHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    loggermodule.module_logger.addHandler(guiHandler)
    loggermodule.module_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    mytextscroll = tk.Scrollbar(app, command=mytext.yview, orient="vertical")
    mytextscroll.grid(row=6, column=3, sticky="ns")
    mytext.configure(yscrollcommand=mytextscroll.set)

    root.mainloop()
```

Below is how I'm expecting the GUI to look. (How it looks when I dont use classes and build it straight)

[image: Correct GUI using no classes]

and this is how it looks when I use classes and is giving me the incorrect placement

[image: Incorrect Gui using classes]

Comment: Please include the actual, complete  error in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley the error depends on how I attempt to fix the situation. Thats why I added screenshots of how it's supposed to look (when I write the code without classes) and how it does look when I use the code that I have included above. I'm not sure what i"m doing wrong. So the error is based really on what I try to do to fix it. For example if I try to use tk.TK__init(SMNPPAGE,...) it will tell me SNMP has no attribute TK. Just as an example

Comment: If your question mentions an error, the code in the questions should produce that error, and you need to include the error in the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley my question only mentions an error in the context of what I get when I try to fix a problem, not the issue itself. My issue is apparent in the screenshots of how the application looks versus how its supposed to look and I can't figure out in my code using classes where i'm going wrong

Comment: good question. also, if I was u, if u already decided to hide the IP then maybe you should do that in all of the screenshots?